# scala how to print a Future.sequence

Tags: scala, playframework

I've got this construct:

```
projectDao.getProjectIdsByUserId(userId).map(ids => ids.map(id => toProject(id, userId)))
  .map(Future.sequence(_)) /* transform Future[Seq[Future[...]]] to Future[Future[Seq[...]]] */
```

how can I print the result of this in console?

in the project data should be a city which I want to print in console

is that possible and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating data that matches your original question:

```
val originalFuts : Seq[Future[Int]] = 
  Seq(
    Future.successful(1), 
    Future.successful(2), 
    Future.successful(3)
  )

val fut : Future[Seq[Future[Int]]] = Future.successful(originalFuts)
```

You can access the underlying `Integer` values with for comprehension:

```
for {
  seq <- fut
  f <- seq
  i <- f
} {
  println(i)
}
```

**Simplify**

You can make your data structure simpler with a minor modification

```
val futSeq = 
  projectDao
    .getProjectIdsByUserId(userId)
    .flatMap(ids => Future sequence (ids map (toProject(_, userId)))
```

Which can then be handled with a simpler

```
for {
  seq <- futSeq
  i   <- seq
} {
  println(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most straightforward approach would be via a `foreach` function, e.g:

```
val future = Future(...)
future.foreach(println)
```

Please note that i'm calling `foreach` separately, using it in the call chain would lead to a different result type.

In your case, if you have a type `Future[Future[...]]`, you need to call `flatten` to get a flat `Future[...]`, but i guess you can double-check you chain and maybe replace one of your `map` call with `flatMap`, to simplify it. I guess that would be something like this:

```
projectDao
  .getProjectIdsByUserId(userId)
  .map(ids => ids.map(id => toProject(id, userId)))
  .flatMap(Future.sequence(_))
```

then just put it somewhere and log:

```
val results = projectDao.getPro...
results.foreach(println)
```

Or you can use `Future.traverse`:

```
Future.traverse(projectDao.getProjectIdsByUserId(userId)) { id =>
  log.info(...)
  toProject(id, userId)
}
```